# How to generalize MATRIX-MULTIPLY-RECURSIVE to multiply n × n matrices?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, recurrence-relation, matrices, divide-and-conquer

the question is as follows:

"Generalize MATRIX-MULTIPLY-RECURSIVE to multiply n × n matrices for which n is not necessarily an exact power of 2. Give a recurrence describing its running time. Argue that it runs in Θ(n^3) time in the worst case."

how do you go about solving this?

my solution to the first part of the question went like this:

```
MATRIX-MULTIPLY-RECURSIVE(A, B, C, n)
    if n == 1
      //Base case.
      C_11 = C_11 + A_11 * B_11
      Return
    //Divide
    if n is odd
       Let Ap, Bp and Cp be new d * d empty matrices where d = n+1
       for i = 2 to d
           for j = 1 to d-1
               Ap_ij = A_(i-1)j
               Bp_ij = B_(i-1)j
       for k = 1 to d
           Ap_1k = 0
           Ap_kd = 0
           Bp_1k = 0
           Bp_kd = 0
    else
        Let Ap = A, Bp = B, Cp = C, and d = n
    Partition Ap, Bp, and Cp into d/2 * d/2 submatrices 
    A1, A2, A3, A4;B1, B2, B3, B4;
    and C1, C2, C3, C4; respectively
    MATRIX-MULTIPLY-RECURSIVE(A1, B1, C1, d/2)
    MATRIX-MULTIPLY-RECURSIVE(A2, B2, C2, d/2)
    MATRIX-MULTIPLY-RECURSIVE(A3, B3, C3, d/2)
    MATRIX-MULTIPLY-RECURSIVE(A4, B4, C4, d/2)
```

how do I argue that it runs in n^3 time in worst case? and is my solution correct?...

Comment: What's the use of variable d ?